# Converting a denormalized single-precision IEEE-754 to fixed-point

Tags: ieee-754

Let me explain the case briefly: task is to design hardware modules for conversion between fixed-point and single-precision floating point numbers.
So far,I came up with the idea of a fixed-point representation,in which index of point is can also be specified.So with a 128-bit input to fixedToFloat module,I can represent greatest and smallest(in magnitude,not in manner of closeness to zero) normalized floating point numbers. Due to lots of shifters and multiplexers,design already has a deep critical path.

Apparently, 128-bit input length is not enough for covering all denormalized numbers(except zero,and 2^-127 by setting fixed point index to 127 and leftmost bit of the input to 1). Is there a way of representing denormalized numbers without increasing the bit-length from 128 to 128+22(to represent numbers such as 2^-135 for instance) ?

Note that design does not have any commercial purposes,that's why I use a non-pipelined combinational  design with 128-bit input length. Correctness is the first issue,as long as the module meets a couple of latency requirements.

Comment: Simplest solution: keep the sign, but treat all subnormals as zero.

Comment: I actually proposed that idea(rounding every denormal to zero) about half an hour ago,lets see what they have to say :D